# Client-server application - how to send queries to database and receive results?

Tags: java, android, database, client-server

I'm writing client-server application where the client is an android v2.1 application and the server is written in Java and has a connection to a MySQL database. The connection between the client and the server is TCP encrypted with SSL. Currently, I'm wondering how to send queries from client to database and receive results back to client. I would like to be able to carry more complex queries, such as retrieving data from multiple tables. I would choose the most optimal solution for efficiency and simplicity, so please justify your answer and give me a best way to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to create REST server side, that's the preferred and most secure solution. Don't create direct **Android-(remote)MySQL** connection

Answer (score 1):

Your client should be agnostic as to the inner workings of your server,(your client shouldn't care whether the server is written in Java, php or rails, as well the structure of the tables). I would start off by defining your requirements of your client service, and then have your server provide a REST interface to the requirements of the client.

From there the client would just communicate via HTTPRequests, JSON would be the easiest format for the posts, imo. Your server would then handle the complexity of how the data is arranged among the various tables, and how to query the tables to provide the implementation for previously defined interfaces.